# как можно открыть консоль (не idle) на мак для Sublime text

Tags: python

Я пробовал гуглит не мне всегда выдавал идл но я не смог в нем разобраться

Comment: В Sublime нельзя открыть консоль в привычном понимании. Но можно получить вывод программы. Для этого есть сочетание клавиш `Ctrl` + `B` (**B**uild).

Comment: ctrl+` но это не bash коноль. а python

Comment: спс я решил по гуглить на английском и поискать там и нашел ответ. но всеравно спс